# Adding Press Enter functionality in input

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to add an event listener as <kbd>enter</kbd> key but I could not get it working as nothing happens when I click on <kbd>enter</kbd> key in input form after typing something. Please check my code:

HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
    <div>
        <h2>Enter Today's Money</h2>
        <input type='text' id="input"></input>
        <button onclick="clicked()">GO</button>
        <h1>Today {total}</h1>
        <h1>This Month {month}</h1>
        <h1> This Year {year} </h1>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JS -

```
let input = document.querySelector("input");
if(input){
    input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.key === 'Enter'){
            alert('clicked');
        }
    });
}
function clicked(){
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("input");
    var value = inputVal.value;
    console.log(value);
}
```

I have been trying for many months now but could not trigger any event after <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed in input form.

Comment: You should load the script at the end (*right before the `</body>` tag*). Right now it is running before the elements you query for are available.

Comment: the script is loaded even before the input element is parsed, that's why event listener is not being registered. you tried to suppress the error by adding `if(input)`, load script at the end of body tag, or use `defer` inside script tag